# removing phpbb tag using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove a rectangular brackets(bbcode style) using javascript, this is for removing unwanted bbcode.
I try with this.

```
theString .replace(/\[quote[^\/]+\]*\[\/quote\]/, "")
```

it works with this string sample:

```
theString = "[quote=MyName;225]Test 123[/quote]";
```

it will fail within this sample:

```
theString = "[quote=MyName;225]Test [quote]inside quotes[/quote]123[/quote]";
```

if there any solution beside regex no problem

Comment: You could check whether, after replacing, the regexp still matches. In that case, use the replace code again, until all occurences have been replaced.

Comment: that will not work because the first replace will match only like this: **[quote=MyName;225]Test [quote]inside quotes[/quote]** 123[/quote]" and after that the regex will not match again.

Comment: You're correct - one would actually need to work from inner quotes to outer quotes. Never mind my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other 2 solutions simply do not work (see my comments). To solve this problem you first need to craft a regex which matches the innermost matching quote elements (which contain neither `[QUOTE..]` nor `[/QUOTE]`). Next, you need to iterate, applying this regex over and over until there are no more QUOTE elements left. This tested function does what you want:

```js
function filterQuotes(text)
{ // Regex matches inner [QUOTE]non-quote-stuff[/quote] tag.
    var re = /\[quote[^\[]+(?:(?!\[\/?quote\b)\[[^\[]*)*\[\/quote\]/ig;
    while (text.search(re) !== -1)
    { // Need to iterate removing QUOTEs from inside out.
        text = text.replace(re, "");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Note that this regex employs Jeffrey Friedl's "*Unrolling the loop*" efficiency technique and is not only accurate, but is quite fast to boot.

See: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) (highly recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
/\[quote[^\/]+\].*\[\/quote\]$/
```

The $ sign indicates that only the closing quote element at the end of the string should be used to determine the ending of the quote you're trying to remove.

And i added a "." before the asterisk so that this will match any sign in between. I tested this with your two strings and it worked.

edit: I don't exactly know how you are using that. But just as an addition. If you want the pattern also to match to a string where no attributes are added for example:

```
[quote]Hello[/quote]
```

You should change the "+" sign into an asterisk as well like this:

```
/\[quote[^\/]*\].*\[\/quote\]$/
```

Comment: yes it work, but its not working if there is another string after the [/quote]

Comment: This regex: `/\[quote[^\/]*\].*\[\/quote\]$/` does not work. It fails when two QUOTEs are in series with good data between. e.g. `[quote]Hello1[/quote] this gets deleted too! [quote]Hello2[/quote]`

Comment: Yes that was the idea. The whole comment block is supposed to be deleted i think...

Answer (score 0):

**This answer has flaws, see Ridgerunner's answer for a more correct one.**

Here's my crack at it.

```
function filterQuotes(text)
{
    return text.replace(/\[(\/)?quote([^\/]*)?\]/g,"");
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, welcome to the community.  Don't forget to accept/promote answers.

Comment: This regex: `/\[(\/)?quote([^\/]*)?\]/g` does not work. Things go bad if there are any other tags inside the QUOTE. e.g. `[quote]Hello [i]there[\i] world![/quote]`